# Why DC voltage can't be generated at audio port of a smartphone using AudioTrack library?

Tags: java, android, audio, adc, digital-analog-converter

I am building an android application to generate signals like Sine, Square, Sawtooth and DC. I have been able generate sine,sqaure and sawtooth waves by generating values and filling these values to the buffer through which I write to audio port using AudioTrack class. For DC I am writing a constant value 1 to the buffer and writing to audio port. But this is not generating any output when I connect mobile to CRO.

After referring few docs, I found that the audio I/O of mobile is designed to pass changing signals only. Can someone elaborate what exactly this means? Why do we have such constraint ?is it because DAC can't convert a constant values to analog ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I somehow do not believe that this is Java specific, actually more like device design...  I could imagine that constant values are filtered out because it is a sound port, no need for DC (ay harm some equipment?)

Comment: Right. This is not java specific. For some reason,no android devices support DC at it's audio port. Apparently this looks like some hardware limitation(like DAC). Just trying to know the exact reason.